# Can you adapt a premade model from tf.keras.applications for 1D time-series data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras, resnet

I am looking to use ResNet50 as a preprocessing module/feature extractor for a transformer-like time-series classification architecture. Unfortunately, all the pre-made feature extractors in the tf.keras.applications module seem to be for image data. I obviously cannot just specify input_tensor = (5000,12) as the model expects 3 dimensions.

Is there any way around this or ill I have to build the models myself from scratch?

Cheers

Tom

Comment: The model is designed for three dimensional data, how should it work for two dimensional data? And even if it somehow was possible to e.g. transform all 2D convolutional layers to 1D convolutional layers (which it is not), then the pretrained weights would not fit any more. And additionally, pretraining is only useful if the new application for the model is at least remotely similar to the original application, which it is seemingly not in your case.

Comment: I'm looking to use a ResNet50 with 1D convolutions as a pre-processor for a tim-series classifier. I believe that in theory, the architecture shpould do a good job at my problem and I wasn't intending to use pre-trained weights.
Thanks for clarifying thoug!